# Window.Open in chrome opens both popus and new tab

Tags: php, javascript, tcpdf

I have a strange problem in chrome, I am using window.open to open a new tab and create a pdf using tcpdf and then send it as attachment to a specific address, now in chrome what happens is that it sends 2 mails. If popup is enabled then I get 2 window actions 1. Popup and 2. New Tab, firstly I don't understand how is that possible, I have never seen this.

Then If is disable the popup, it only opens in new tab, but still 2 mails.

Code used to call the popup page and email code is mentioned below. Please help.

```
window.open('/loancal/rhexportemail.php' + qstring,"_blank");
//Code used to open popup 

//------------- EMAIL CODE ----------------//
$to = "someone@gamil.com";
$from = "info@mydomain.com";
$subject = "Loan Enquiry Calculation Cashback - " . $client;
$message = "Please find attached Loan Enquiry Calculation Cashback statement for ".$client."."  ;

//a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = $subject.".pdf";

// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output('LECC'.$separator.'.pdf', 'S');
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// encode data (multipart mandatory)
 $headers = "From: ".$from.$eol;
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
 $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol;
 $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Enconding: 7bit".$eol; 
 $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;

 // message
 $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charsrt=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
 $headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;

 // attachment
 $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
 $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
 $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
 $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
 $headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
 $headers .= "--".$separator."--";

 // send message
 if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
 {

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('mail sent');window.close();</script>";

 }
 else{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('mail not sent');window.close();  </script>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that you somehow call this twice.

Comment: its not the case, try this.. create a page and add a window.open code and have a javascript alert set on page load. Now have the popup blocker disabled for that page, you will see both the popup window and a new tab opening at the the same time. I believe that chrome is not suppressing the php code even when popup is blocked, use the PHP code provided below to call alert.    

`echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('mail sent');</script>";`